# chrome responded with "could not load resource" on trying to get api data

Tags: javascript, compiler-errors, http-status-code-404

im trying to get the response of an api call on my chrome console but it kept spitting could not laod response **404**

this is the main response

main.js:62 GET http://localhost:3000/[object%20Object] 404 (Not Found)

Comment: What the question? What has your script achieved so far?

Comment: Please provide `main.js` in order for us to find what went wrong in your code. I'm suspecting you didn't use `JSON.stringify()` (from looking at `[object Object]` that I've seen probably a thousand times).